# Error related to only_full_group_by when executing a query in MySql on Server, working fine on local machine

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring-boot

`SELECT new com.example.car.entities.MonthMapper(DATE_FORMAT(car.boughtDate,'%Y-%m'), SUM(total), COUNT(chassis_no)) FROM Car car WHERE  DATE_FORMAT(car.boughtDate,'%Y/%m') >= DATE_FORMAT(:fromDate,'%Y/%m') GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(car.boughtDate,'%Y/%m');`

As I am already mentioning boughtDate after group by

Comment: Not sure but looking at other DATE_FORMAT parts of your query, you may want to replace "-" with "/" in the part: MonthMapper(DATE_FORMAT(car.boughtDate,'%Y-%m').
Also, this might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql

Comment: Error is still there after replacing "-" with "/", means after making both DATE_FORMAT same. 
Yes, I already looked into that link but I am not able to solve my issue specifically.

Comment: There's something missing after new SELECT new com.

Answer (score 0):

The published code does not syntax on my local machine. Here's some errors

There's something missing after new SELECT new com
com.example.car.entities.MonthMapper is possibly a column which should have a comma after it
(DATE_FORMAT(car.boughtDate,'%Y-%m'), SUM(total), COUNT(chassis_no)) is incorrectly bracketed and should be (DATE_FORMAT(car.boughtDate,'%Y-%m')), SUM(total), COUNT(chassis_no)

Also I suspect there are too many nodes in com.example.car.entities.MonthMapper